# Null Pointer Exception Java Eclipse NEON

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

Error processing requestContext Path:/Employees

Servlet Path:/Dipendente

Path Info:null

Query String:null

Stack Trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
it.proxima.dipendenti.dao.DipendenteDAO.getDipendente(DipendenteDAO.java:53)
```

This is DAO

```
 public class DipendenteDAO 
{
private Connection con;
private Statement cmd;
private static DipendenteDAO istance;

public static DipendenteDAO getIstance()
{
    if(istance == null) istance = new DipendenteDAO();
    return istance;
}

private DipendenteDAO()
{
    try 
    {   
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) new 
        InitialContext().lookup("java:jboss/datasources/andreadb");

        Connection con = ds.getConnection();
        System.out.println("con:"+con);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Dipendente getDipendente(String Codicefiscale)
{
    Dipendente result = null;
    try
    {
        // Eseguiamo una query e immagazziniamone i risultati in un oggetto 
        ResultSet   
        String qry = "SELECT * FROM dipendenti WHERE Codicefiscale 
        ='"+Codicefiscale+"'";
        ResultSet res = cmd.executeQuery(qry);

        while(res.next())
        {
            result = new Dipendente();
            result.setNome(res.getString("Nome"));
            result.setCodicefiscale("Codicefiscale");
            result.setCognome(res.getString("Cognome"));
            result.setDatadinascita(res.getDate("Datadinascita"));
            result.setLuogodinascita(res.getString("Luogodinascita"));
        }
    } 
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        // Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;

}
```

this is the Servlet code

```
@WebServlet("/Dipendente")
public class DipendenteServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



public Dipendente getAnagrafica(String Cf)
{
    DipendenteDAO dd = DipendenteDAO.getIstance();
    Dipendente dip = dd.getDipendente(Cf);
    if(dip == null) System.out.println("ERRORE: Codice fiscale non presente 
    nel sistema");
    else System.out.println(dip.getNome() + " " + dip.getCognome());
    dd.close();
    return dip;
}
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String codiceFiscale = request.getParameter("Codice_Fiscale");
    Dipendente ds = this.getAnagrafica(codiceFiscale);

    response.getWriter().append(ds.getNome()+" "+ds.getCognome());



}
```

does anyone know what might depend?

Line 53 of the error is this :

```
53: ResultSet res = cmd.executeQuery(qry);
```

in debug mode, the statement cmd is null

Initializing cmd i get the same error. Maybe there's another mistake in the connection con ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cmd` is...

```
private Statement cmd;
```

...but you never assign anything to it. So how do you expect it to be anything else then `null`? Trying to call a method on a `null` object, will result in a `NullPointerException`.

What you are missing is something like this before Line 53...

```
cmd = con.createStatement();
```

This will let the `Connection` object create a new `Statement` and assign that to your `cmd` variable.

Also please note that this...

```
Connection con = ds.getConnection();
```

...means that the...

```
private Connection con;
```

...will also be always `null`, resulting in the same problem. Replace it with...

```
con = ds.getConnection();
```

Explanation: With your code, you are creating a NEW variable `con`, which is only valid in the constructor, while the other variable, also named `con`, will still be `null`. This is not what you want. You want to create a `Connection` somehow and assign it to the already existing variable `con`, not create a new variable `con` that will be forgotten as soon as the constructor is done.

Comment: Initializing cmd i get the same error. Maybe there's another mistake in the connection con ?

Comment: Most likely that's because of the other bug in your code, I updated the answer.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the Statement with:

```
cmd = con.createStatement();
```

before

```
ResultSet res = cmd.executeQuery(qry);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html

Comment: Initializing cmd i get the same error. Maybe there's another mistake in the connection con ?